# AWS Device Farm - Run Stuck at Pending (with Errored Status)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, automated-tests, appium, aws-device-farm

I am working on automating testing for my company using Appium Python + AWS Device Farm for iOS devices.

However, when I uploaded my .ipa file and Appium Python test to AWS Device farm, the run stuck and showed me that the status is "Errored", and if I click into the run for a detailed view, it says "Pending" on all of the device runs (See screenshots below: )

[image: Errored]

[image: Pending]

I am pretty sure it is not the problem with my Appium Python test script, because when combining the same script with another .ipa file (from another App), the run works fine on AWS Device Farm. The thing is that by using the same handling, I was able to export .ipa off other App and had them run just fine on AWS Device Farm. This only happens to this particular .ipa file of the same App, but it is the company's official App that I must automate the test for, so I can't just not test it.

Does anyone know how I could fix this problem?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you see why you get error? I think better way to know about that is to write a mail to AWS technical support team

Comment: Since this is related to your tests and you've also [posted on the AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245483&tstart=0), let's continue the discussion within the forum where someone from the product team can assist.